# Event.preventDefault() failing in Jquery on all browsers

Tags: jquery

Simple question.  I have the following HTML:

```
<a  rel="nofollow" id="claim-job-link" data-method="post" class="button green claim-job" href=""><span class="button"> <span class="text"> Claim Job </span> </span></a>
```

And the following Jquery:

```
 $("#claim-job-link").bind('click', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
    });
```

which is called with no problems.  Adding a breakpoint to the preventDefault shows that it is called.  However, the browser is still redirected in both Chrome and Firefox.  Anyone faced anything similar?

---

Edited to add

It looks like the the event is prevented at first and then jquery enters this code block:

```
 for ( i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        match = elems[i];

        if ( maxLevel && match.level > maxLevel ) {
            break;
        }

        event.currentTarget = match.elem;
        event.data = match.handleObj.data;
        event.handleObj = match.handleObj;

        ret = match.handleObj.origHandler.apply( match.elem, arguments );

        if ( ret === false || event.isPropagationStopped() ) {
            maxLevel = match.level;

            if ( ret === false ) {
                stop = false;
            }
            if ( event.isImmediatePropagationStopped() ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return stop;
}
```

Then when it exits, it runs the does the redirect call.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any handlers set on either of the child `span` elements?

Comment: That could be the problem... maybe you are preventing propagation of the event from the span?

Comment: As I look elsewhere in my app, it seems like this is happening with all my preventDefault calls.  Is there something system-wide that may be affecting the call?  @Juan @lone - Nope, no handling of the spans goes on.

Comment: Possible to post a link? Have you modified jQuery?

Comment: Things continue to get weirder.  I just cleared out all of my application.js except for that call, and then moved the link to plain <a href> and it still doesnt work.  Pretty weird.  I even stripped out non-essential jquery libraries.  Could there be some kind of rails/gem interaction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.  I figured it out though.  In a rails app, when you call either :remote=>true or :method=>:xxx, it adds a tag to the link.  This tag is processed by the rails app in such a way that the event.preventDefault call doesn't work.  By removing the :method attribute, the call now works.  Go figure.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: What is the actual HTML that is output? That's what should have been posted in the first place

Comment: It was posted in the first place.  *data-method="post"* was causing the call to fail.

Comment: Adding data-method='post' does not cause it to fail for me! My answer has a link to an example just like you posted that does work. Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: Your link isnt in a rails environment.  Try it on rails :)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. http://jsbin.com/ateje4/edit There must be something else happening. I would create a reduction from your page to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Note: `bind` is additive. Try this:

```
$("#claim-job-link").unbind('click').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Even if you add multiple handlers, calling event.preventDefault() from one of them should still work. However, it is very likely that another handler, either on the same node or within it, is calling stopPropagation(); OP needs to figure what other parts of his code are interacting with those nodes.

Comment: Well, we can talk all day about what "should" or "shouldn't" work, but without more code from him it's all just a guessing game.